# Diagnose Mac OS X Address Book LDAP problems

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, active-directory, address-book, ldap

I've configured a LDAP server in my Address Book preferences on Snow Leopard. I determined the base DN from a helpful recipe on the web using `ldapsearch`.

I never get any search results. Has anyone got a way to force Address Book to reveal what it's doing? I can't tell if it's having connection problems, or ldap problems, or what.

Comment: Have you tried using LDAP from Mail, to see if you have problems there also?

Comment: yes. It crashes mail altogether when I have this ldap server turned on (!)

Answer (score 1):

Most directory servers maintain a log of client access. Examine this log, it will contain each request and result issued by Address Book. For example:

```
[27/May/2011:05:59:14.672 -0400] CONNECT conn=11 from="127.0.0.1" to="127.0.0.1" protocol="LDAP" clientConnectionPolicy="Restrictive client connection policy."
[27/May/2011:05:59:14.879 -0400] SEARCH RESULT conn=11 op=0 msgID=1 base="dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 filter="(&(|(givenname=user*)(sn=user*)(mail=user*)(cn=user*)))" attrs="givenName,sn,cn,mail,telephoneNumber,facsimileTelephoneNumber,o,title,ou,buildingName,street,l,st,postalCode,c,jpegPhoto,mobile,co,pager,destinationIndicator,IMHandle,labeledURI,appleAIMpreferred" resultCode=11 message="This search operation has checked the maximum of 5000 entries for matches" etime=204.608 entriesReturned=0
```

This shows that the operator had typed the string *user* into the search box of address book. Address Book searched the directory server for attributes *givenName*, *sn*, *mail*, and *cn* where the attribute began with the value *user*. The Address Book requests a large number of attributes that, should entries be returned from the search, will be used to create Address Book entries.

Comment: Sadly, I can't easily get inside the logging of the MS Active Directory which is the ldap server in question.